Unsupported Gradle Version in Android Studio 2024.1.2.12 after new install
Just installed Android Studio 2024.1.2.12 and receive Gradle Version and Gradle Wrapper errors after creating an Empty Activity. I followed the instructions in the error descriptions but the error remained - I confirmed the Gradle Version as 8.7 in the Project Structure and the gradle-wrapper.properties > disturtionUrl as gradle-8.7-bin.zip
Error: "Unsupported Gradle Version"
Error Description: "Failed to get a Gradle version. This could happen because of invalid or outdated Gradle wrapper. We recommend upgrading to Gradle version 8.5. Possible solution: - Upgrade to Gradle 8.5 and re-sync"

Error: "Gradle Sync Issues"
Error Description: "Minimum supported Gradle version is 8.7. Current version is 8.5. Please fix the project's Gradle settings. Change Gradle version in Gradle wrapper to 8.7 and re-import project Open Gradle wrapper properties Gradle Settings."


SO is a question and answer site, not a blog. If you have a problem, have discovered a solution to it, and want to share it here, you have to do it properly. First, write a question that meets the same quality guidelines as any other question here. You can then post an answer that contains that solution in the space provided below for answering. See Can I answer my own question? for more details.

My gradle-wrapper.properties file's distributionUrl was ...-bin.zip
Change the distributionUrl to ...-all.zip. Then Sync Project With Gradle Files (in File Drop-down)
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-8.7-all.zip
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists 

I have no clue why it worked but it did.
